# Remove wpautop from shortcode content / remove whitespace in buffering

Tags: shortcode, wp-autop, plugin-mailchimp

I am using the [Mailchimp plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mailchimp/), and it has a shortcode that uses output buffering to grab its widget's code and spit it out in the content.

However, the widget code has plenty of white space, so the_content filters are throwing useless linebreaks (like after hidden inputs) and empty `p` tags everywhere... rendering it unusable. I am removing the shortcode to add my own, but I'm not sure what to do to prevent the WordPress wpautop filter from going crazy. My initial thought was to strip out the whitespaces between HTML tags, but I don't know how to go about doing that.

Ideally, the plugin would concatenate a string to return instead of using output buffering, but I don't know if they'll ever bother.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not need a plugin to do this. Just add 3 lines of code to the end of the `functions.php` file in your active theme:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 99 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop', 100 );
```

Comment: i don't know what exactly i was smoking the other day, but i'm not even experiencing this problem today.  thanks for the answer though.  i think it causes some trouble as HTML comments seem to get wrapped in p tags.

Answer (score 4):

[shea's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55782/remove-wpautop-from-shortcode-content-remove-whitespace-in-buffering/55783#55783) is a nice solution, but it turns off autop for all shortcodes which may not be desired.

I wrote a script that allows you to run the following:

```
include "shortcode-wpautop-control.php";
chiedolabs_shortcode_wpautop_control(array('yourshortcode'));
```

It allows you to turn off wpautop for specific shortcodes instead of all of them.

Once again, I wrote the script. I don't mean to self promote, but as I update it in the future, I will update it on GitHub, so it makes no sense to post the code here.

You can see the script at *[Shortcode wp-autop control](https://github.com/chiedolabs/shortcode-wpautop-control)*.

Comment: Are you actively maintaining this code? It looks useful but I don't wanna invest any time into something that isn't being actively maintained.

Comment: Good question. I'd say I'm not actively maintaining it since not many people have been using it since I launched it. I have WordPress plugins using it that depend on it though so if there are Issues placed on GitHub, I will fix them.

Comment: So I'm reactively maintaining the code as opposed to actively.

Comment: Ok fair enough.

Comment: I would use this, but I need wpautop for parts of my shortcode contents, just not in between the shortcodes. Example: `[row] \n [cell] \n content \n [/cell] [/row]` should become `<row><cell><br>content<br></cell></row>`

Comment: Want to submit a pull request?

Answer (score 2):

There is a WordPress function available that does this job nicely. There isn't any need to use a custom function or a plugin to do this.

Just use the `shortcode_unautop($pee)` function to *remove* wpautop from shortcode content. Here `$pee` is the required string.

Comment: What is the meaning of the word *"pee"*? An abbr. of some kind? [Wiktionary lists five different meanings](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pee) (as a noun).