# How to prevent wordpress from autoformatting my posts once and for all?

Tags: formatting

I am using ifttt to sync my wordpress blog with my blogger site, and there is a problem of auto-formatting on wordpress's side. It likes inserting `<br>` everywhere when exporting posts. For example, a list on wordpress looks like this:

[image]

After syncing, the list looks like this on blogger:

[image]

Leaving the syncing scenario aside, Wordpress does this to its own posts, too. I had to disable the `wpautop` function in `wp-include/formatting.php` to prevent it from inserting those annoying `<br>` tags.  But I don't know which function to disable in the current case. **If possible I would like to disable all forms of autoformatting once and for all, because I always use html for markup and there is no need for WP to reformat for me at all.**

Comment: See this link - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130075/stop-wordpress-automatically-adding-br-tags-to-post-content

Comment: I did something more radical than that already: I commented out the whole wpautop function. WP still inserts `<br>` when posting contents on blogger.

Comment: Have you tried `remove_all_filters( 'the_content' );` and `remove_all_filters( 'the_excerpt' );` ?

Comment: Where should I put these two commands? Thanks!

Comment: Anyways, I have put these two lines into wp-settings.php, haven't seen any effect yet.