# What hook runs wpautop on template content?

Tags: shortcode, hooks, templates, block-editor, wp-autop

I have a shortcode that outputs HTML and I've inserted it into a single post template. The output gets extraneous `<br/>` and `<p>` tags, which I've read in other topics are likely due to `wpautop` being run on the content. The solutions suggested all have to do with removing or changing the priority of this function when attached to the `the_content` hook. But in my case the shortcode is part of the template and not the post content, so this doesn't apply. (Oddly enough the shortcode output doesn't get messed up at all when it's inserted in the post content itself, so probably recent versions of Wordpress have changed behaviour since this issue was obvserved happening in post content).

My question is **how can I prevent my shortcode output from getting messed up with extraneous paragraph and linebreak tags when it's used as part of a template**? I'm using Wordpress 6.2 with Gutenberg editor and a block theme that supports full-site editing.

Minimal working example:

```
function foo() {
  ob_start();
?>
<div>
  <span data-id="foo">
  <span>
</div>
<?php
  $s = ob_get_clean();
  error_log($s, false); // output is fine here, no <br/> tag obviously
  return $s;
}
add_shortcode( 'foo', 'foo' );
```

When I use `[foo]` as part of the post content, all is good, the HTML above is inserted as is, but when I use `[foo]` as part of a single post template, there is a `<br/>` inserted after the first `<span>` tag.

Comment: Did you find this? Describes various ways to manipulate wpautop in relation to shortcodes https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55782/remove-wpautop-from-shortcode-content-remove-whitespace-in-buffering . E.g. try the answer that rehooks things in functions.php?

Comment: Hi, yes, I did find this question but as I mentioned this hook is not relevant since it is called only on the post content and not on template contents. And my question is is there an equivalent hook for template content, or any other way to fix my issue.

Comment: When you add the shortcode to the template are you adding it with  the Shortcode block or typing into into another block?

Comment: I've tried both the Shortcode block and typing it into a paragraph block: same thing happens in both cases.